# Getting error when I use @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to enable global method security.

The problem is when I add the annotation `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` - I get an error as following:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTrustResolver' 
parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'getAuthenticationTrustResolver': 
Requested bean is currently in creation: 
Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    ... 189 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'getAuthenticationTrustResolver': 
Requested bean is currently in creation: 
Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    ... 211 more
```

The problem is from AuthenticationTrustResolver bean

This is the security config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers("/test/**").permitAll().
                antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')").
                and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").
                defaultSuccessUrl("/success-callback").
                loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").
                and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository).
                tokenValiditySeconds(86400 * 2);
//                and().
//                csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/api/**").ignoringAntMatchers("/test/**");

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
                "remember-me", userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
        return tokenBasedservice;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }

}
```

TIA

Comment: Because there is a circular dependency (1) Can you post the `AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl` code? (2) Who should use the `getAuthenticationTrustResolver` bean?

Comment: I am using persistent login, so the AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl is the default spring security impl for AuthenticationTrustResolver with basic default methods such as getAnonymousClass ,isAnonymous @ManuelJordan

Comment: What version of spring boot, spring security, etc do you use?

Comment: This is my pom.xml lib properties

<springframework.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>

Comment: I am also facing same issue , my spring boot version is 1.5.9. Any pointers?

Comment: I am not using spring security

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to update your spring security to the latest version (`4.2.3.RELEASE`)!